# Inverse of Laplacian and Gaussian Noise

Tags: probability, gaussian

Given a set of data points, I modify the data points by adding a Laplacian or a Gaussian Noise to them.

I am wondering if there exist mathematical inverse functions able to derive the original data points from the ones with noise.

My understanding is that, we can reconstruct only an estimation of the original data points that have a certain probability ***p*** of being equal to the original data points.

If this is the case, how to calculate such a probability ***p***?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise: reconstructing the original points while given the noise-parameters (variance) or without? Are you interested in the probability-density of the curve (possible reconstruction-realizations) or the reconstructed vector itself? And is information available about the original curve or not? Without information about the original curve, there should be no good *inverse function*, even in principle (assumptions or regulizations needed). Keyword: **curve-fitting**

Comment: @sascha Assume you know both mean value and variance. I am interested in the probability of reconstructing the "vector" (data points).

Comment: What's the use-case? How do we calculate the error-metric? Exact reconstruction (on continuous values) or discretized reconstruction? Even with a discretized reconstruction / binning; i would assume, that even for 30 samples, the probability of exactly (each bin correct) reconstructing the vector already vanished -> nearly equal to zero. Reconstructing the original data / the most probable vector, given mean/variance could be tackled by general nonlinear programming techniques. But in this case, i would think that you need *some* samples to get a good solution (which is then costly).

Comment: Assume you have 1000 samples (to each of them has been added noise)  and you know the mean and standard deviation for such noise. What is the probability that you can obtain the original 1001 data point by knowing all the noisy 1001 data points?

Comment: I don't think that this is a nice formulation. The probability of predicting the value of sample 1001 will be 0, as there are infinite many possible values for this point, as the normal-distribution is not limited. In my opinion, you have to discretize or ask for something like: how high is the probability of an error <= 0.01 * std.